# How to make sure that my software is connected to the right server?

Tags: c#, .net, security, ssl, trust

I've got a server which identifies itself with an ssl certificate. The certificate is self signed.

I want to make sure that the software won't send data, if the user tries to replace server and add "fake" certificate to the list of certificates trusted by the operating system.

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateRemoteCertificate;

private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (sender is HttpWebRequest)
    {
        var wr = sender as HttpWebRequest;
        if (wr.Address.Host == "<my host>")
        {
            if (cert == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (cert.GetCertHashString() == "<certificate hash string>")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The way I understand the code about, it will trust my certificate for `my host`, but it won't be protected from host substitution by the user.

I want the software to accept `my host` only when in identifies itself with the certificate with `<certificate hash string>`, and if `my host` presents an other certificate, the connection must be refused.

How do I do that?

Comment: Before I will answer this question.  Generate two certificates.  Insert the hash for the one certificate and send the other certificate instead.  Report back what happens.

Comment: I think the other comment was getting to the point but still...having the certificate hash string in your code does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: What are trying to protect?   The client is uploading confidential data?  If you have untrusted clients then what would stop them from hacking the data directly?   Is the scenario the certificate would be hacked to get data sent later by another user?  If they are going to hack the certificate what would stop them from hacking the hash code?

Comment: because the other one is self signed, it won't be accepted until I tell the software to, so I tried the thing with https://google.com, and it was rejected. It seems that this code is sufficient after all

Comment: @KenBrittain I'm planning to obfuscate the code afterwards, but if you have a better idea where to place the certificate hash, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: There is no secure place on client for the hash.

Comment: @Blam: yes, the client is uploading confidential data, and second, I want to make it more difficult for potential hackers to monitor the communications between my app and the server using software like fiddler

Comment: I would update the local certificate store and have the toolkit verify the certificate. You doing it manually is not optimal.

Comment: It it just a cost thing to not get a certificate from a provider?

Comment: @Blam it's cost, but mainly I don't see a valid reason to get a certificate from a provider. I don't intend for anyone but my own software to use the service, and the certificate is used mainly for encrypting sensitive data. Regarding hash - it is not sensitive information. Anyone connecting to an ssl website can get the hash of the certificate

Comment: Does the server make the certificate authority used to sign the server certificate available? Installing it in you client machine's trusted root certif autos will tell your software that certificates signed by it (verified by using the certificate authority's public key on the certificate) should be trusted. That should protect you against any spoofing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make sure that my software is connected to the right server?

Since you know the server in advance, you know both the certificate and the public key the server should be using. To leverage that knowledge, you use a technique called pinning. OWASP has a discussion of it at [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).

The code for C# is fairly straight forward. Below is taken from the OWASP page. It connects to Google, and ensures the server is using the expected public key:

```
// Encoded RSAPublicKey
private static String PUB_KEY = "30818902818100C4A06B7B52F8D17DC1CCB47362" +
    "C64AB799AAE19E245A7559E9CEEC7D8AA4DF07CB0B21FDFD763C63A313A668FE9D764E" +
    "D913C51A676788DB62AF624F422C2F112C1316922AA5D37823CD9F43D1FC54513D14B2" +
    "9E36991F08A042C42EAAEEE5FE8E2CB10167174A359CEBF6FACC2C9CA933AD403137EE" +
    "2C3F4CBED9460129C72B0203010001";

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = PinPublicKey;
  WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://encrypted.google.com/");
  wr.GetResponse();
}

public static bool PinPublicKey(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
                                SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  if (null == certificate)
    return false;

  String pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
  if (pk.Equals(PUB_KEY))
    return true;

  // Bad dog
  return false;
}
```

Certificate pinning does not work with Google and a few others. That's because they rotate their certificate every 30 days or so to keep the CRLs small for mobile clients. But they re-certify the same public key to allow key continuity schemes like pinning to work. So public key pinning will work as expected.